# Adding to, cc,subject in Desktop.mail(uri)

Tags: java, email

I am a beginner of using Desktop.mail(URI) class, so I am looking for a way to add to, cc and subject to the mail when triggered from the program.

```
     String mailTo = "test@domain.com";
     String cc = "test2@domain.com";
     String subject = "firstEmail";
     String body = "the java message";

    URI uriMailTo = new URI(mailTo,cc,subject,body);
    Desktop desktop;
    desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
    desktop.mail(uriMailTo);
```

can any one suggest any tutorials to learn this process, because I am looking for even more functions like receiving the data back from the outlook to the Java program.

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: Is it not an option to use javax.mail? https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/overview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Desktop.mail()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#mail%28java.net.URI%29) function is a utility method for launching whatever mail program may exist in the users system (if any). You have (very) limited capability of controlling the actual mail message to be (eventually) sent, and once the mail client is displayed you're pretty much done - aka you wont be getting any feedback on what message was actually sent or wether it succeeded.

If you need this level of control then you should be using the [JavaMail API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/package-summary.html), which does a lot of what you seem to need.

If you are stuck with using the Desktop mail client, then you might want to read up on [RFC 2368](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2368.txt). It describes all the fields that can be included in a `mailto` URI. So, you will be able to populate the message, but you won't get feedback on wether it was successfully sent or not:

```
mailto:joe@example.com?cc=bob@example.com&body=hello+world
```

A code example of constructing your URI (which is incorrect btw):

```
final String mailURIStr = String.format("mailto:%s?subject=%s&cc=%s&body=%s",
    mailTo, subject, cc, body);
final URI mailURI = new URI(mailURIStr);
```

Where the substituted should be URL encoded if necessary.

Comment: Hi there,Thanks for the reply, I have used String.format, but it comes up with lot of errors. Could you please have a look at the code again and let me know if i need to change. Thank you.

Comment: What kind of errors did you get? See edit for slight correction to the string format spec.

Comment: I had forgotten to use the + between the two words in a string, so there are lot of errors, but it is fine now. Thank you.

Comment: I am just wondering if any one has idea about auto send the mails using java.util.Timer, for example for the above code. I am working on it now, any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Hi Everyone! I have a small question, can we add an attachment to it too? a pdf for exemple?

Comment: @Sam - not using any standard part of the specification (http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2368.txt) no. If the user has a mail client that allows for attachments, they can manually elect to do so. Alternatively (and probably a better option) is for you to utilize the JavaMail API.